# Vim how to move csv column

Tags: vim

Suppose a classic csv like this :

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

I was trying to move the 6th column of each line to the beginning of the line using a simple and elegant one liner.

Is there a way to achieve this using something like :

```
g/,/norm 5n<?>d0P
```

I don't know what to put in place of <?> to select the word right after the 5th comma

Comment: I would just use block visual mode. Go to correct column, ctrl+v, go down to the bottom, and then `d0P`.

Comment: Will your data in each cell contain literal `,`(s)?

Comment: yes it will all the lines are in the same format just the length of each cell may vary of course

Comment: @Segfault If your cell is surrounded by double quotes `"` (meaning there is special character in it), I think using Excel might be easier.

Comment: How about using a proper spreadsheet instead? 1. Grab header of column #6. 2. Drag it before column #1. 3. Done.

Comment: `%norm 5f,ldf,0P` would work but I agree with the general sentiment that perhaps you are using the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little modification on the global command

```
:g/./exec 'normal 5f,lvld0P'

:g  .............. globally
/./  ............. on each line that has something
exec ............. execute the following normal command
5f, .............. jumpt to the fifht ,
l ................ move to the number
vl ............... select the number and its coma
d ................ cut to the unamed register
0 ................ jump to the beginning of line
P ................ past the content of default register (before)
```

## Update

Instead of simply selecting the number and the next coma we select until the next coma. (This is a more generic solution), avoiding issues with columns who possibly have double digit or more numbers.

```
g/./exec 'normal 5f,ldf,0P'
```

### Using gnu awk

```
awk -i inplace -F, -v OFS="," '{print 6,1,2,3,4,5,7}' target-file

-i inplace  ............. no need to use temp file
-F ...................... field separator
-v OFS .................. output field separator
```

### Calling awk from vim

```
:%! awk -F, -v OFS="," '{print 6,1,2,3,4,5,7}'

% ............... current file
! ............... filter trhough external command
```